# Embeding Xterm into Qt5 application in c++

Tags: c++, qt, xterm

Sorry if it is duplicate but i can't find anything usefull to me regarding Qt5. Is there any way to embed Xterm into Qt application using c++? I did it with python, but there is problem with resizing xterm on (at least with PyQt5) widget's container resize, in other words xterm doesn't resize, which is not acceptable.

So i want to try with Qt using c++.
Python code (simplified) that worked was:

```
class embeddedTerminal(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, bg='Black'):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

    def startXterm(self):
        self._start_process('xterm',['-embed', str(int(self.winId())), "-bg", self.bg, "-fg", "green"])


    def _start_process(self, prog, args):
        child = QProcess()
        child.start(prog, args)
```

object of embeddedTerminal was inserted into QTab widget later as:

```
term = embeddedTerminal()
term.startXterm()
tabwidget.insertTab(index, term, " Some descriptive text")
```

So i have tried to do similiar thing with c++ like this:

**terminal.h** :

```
class Terminal : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit Terminal(Ui::SuperFalcon *ui) ;
    ~Terminal();
private:
    Ui::SuperFalcon *lui;
};
```

**terminal.cpp :**

```
Terminal::Terminal(Ui::SuperFalcon *ui) : QWidget()
{
   // lui=ui class with all of the Q elements
   lui = ui;

    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    int i_wid = lui->tabWidget_2->winId();
    QString s_wid = QString::fromStdString(to_string(i_wid));
    cout << i_wid << endl;

    QStringList qsl = {"-embed", s_wid, "-bg", "black", "-fg", "green"};
    //    QStringList qsl = {};
    proc->start("/usr/bin/xterm", qsl);    
}
```

and finally it is called in another cpp file that handles all of he gui elements with:

```
Terminal *term = new Terminal(ui);
ui->tabWidget_2->insertTab(0, term, "terminal");
```

I have xterm installed, when i call process with {} empty arguments it starts xterm normally, but when i send QStringList qsl with parameters it doesn't show anything.

Does anyone know how to fix it, i am guessing that window id might be the problem,but i am not that familiar with c++, especially with Qt which can be overwhelming coming from PyQt and python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that xterm does not have the "-embed" command (I don't know if it did) but you must use the "-into" command as [the docs](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/xterm.1.html) point out.

On the other hand, it is not necessary to access the tabwidget or create a QProcess pointer unnecessarily.

Considering the above then the solution is:

```
#ifndef TERMINAL_H
#define TERMINAL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QProcess>

class Terminal : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Terminal(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
private:
    QProcess process;
};

#endif // TERMINAL_H
```

```
#include "terminal.h"


Terminal::Terminal(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QStringList qsl = {"-into", QString::number(winId()),
                       "-bg", "black",
                       "-fg", "green"};
    process.start("/usr/bin/xterm", qsl);
}
```

```
Terminal *term = new Terminal;
ui->tabWidget_2->insertTab(0, term, "terminal");
```

Comment: You are correct, i have found same solution just now, -embeded left from urxvt. Thank you.